# Android studio not working ins spite of having jdk1.8.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is the error that I am getting:

> Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible
>   with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's
>   system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64
>   (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software
>   publisher

Can you please tell me what to do? I created `JDK_HOME` system variable but still it doesn't work.

Comment: What Windows are you using? Seems the error is pretty clear

Comment: The JDK is not the problem. Your CPU or OS is...

Comment: Seeing as x86 Java runs on a x64 machine, you probably have x64 Java trying to run on a x86 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Error seems pretty clear that the program and your operating system architecture do not match.

See the [Android Studio download page](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads).

Make sure you have the right version of Android Studio for the operating system you are using.

i.e., if you are running a 32-bit operating system download the "32-bit" version of Android Studio. If you are using a 64-bit system download the "64-bit" version of Android Studio.